# Overleaf times out if list of figures is produced

Tags: table-of-contents, overleaf

If I use the command `\listoffigures` and compile, Overleaf times out. I tried commenting out every figure, see if any of them is the problem, but it times out anyway.
This is how I use it in a specific subfile:

```
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\hspace{10pt}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

I can only imagine that the problem stems from my preamble but I can't tell why. This is my main.tex which I compile with every other subfile ommited. "00_list_of_tables_and_figures" is the aforementioned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[boxruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\myworries[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\newenvironment{theo}[2][]{%
    \refstepcounter{theo}
 
   \ifstrempty{#1}%
% if condition (without title)
{\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
        \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
        {\strut \textlatin{Theorem}~\thetheo};}
    }%
% else condition (with title)
}{\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
        \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
        {\strut \textlatin{Theorem}~\thetheo:~#1};}%
    }%
}%
% Both conditions
\mdfsetup{%
    innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
    linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
    frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax%
}
 
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax}{%
\end{mdframed}}

% Expectation symbol
\newcommand{\inlineeqnum}{\refstepcounter{equation}~~\mbox{(\theequation)}}
% Expectation symbol
\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}}

\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    \newpage
    \subfile{sections/00_list_of_tables_and_figures}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid I can't replicate the problem you describe, either on Overleaf or on MacTeX2020. BTW, your code does exhibit what is probably an above-average amount of deadwood, repetitive, and subsequently overridden instructions. E.g., don't load the `inputenc` package twice, and don't load the `graphicx` package with the option `dvips` -- unless you truly do compile your tex file first to dvi, then to ps, and finally to pdf. (But why would you do that?) Also, don't run `\pagestyle{headings}` and follow it up immediately with `\pagestyle{empty}`. Do get rid of such stuff.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out. I've edited them out already and there aren't any other repetitve declarations of packages. Unfortunately the problem persists

Comment: Since I can *not* replicate the issue you describe when I compile your code, *as posted above*, on either Overleaf (with plain-vanilla settings) or a standalone MacTeX2020 system, the issue is almost certainly caused by some feature that you haven't divulged so far. If your sample code, *as posted above*, hangs when you compile it on Overleaf, I would start looking at your Overleaf settings.

Comment: _[Disclaimer/Disclosure: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ You may want to check carefully if have a `\\` or `\footnote` inside any of your `\caption{...}`, or any other fragile commands. If you haven't used any commands like these inside \caption, and can't post a complete MWE here, you can contact support@overleaf.com with your project's URL so that someone from the support team can have a look.

Comment: I've tried omiting all of the figures. The problem persisted even with no figures simply from including `\listoffigures` command. I'll try ablating all subfiles one by one see if I can isolate the problem.

Comment: I've edited the post to reflect the smallest reproducible example. Every subfile is ommited ecxept the one that uses `\listoffigures`

Comment: If you're still getting this error after commenting out all figures (i.e. all the \caption): try clearing the auxiliary files in your compile session first, before recompiling. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache

Comment: Apparently this was important. There were a couple of captions that used & instead of \& and even if I commented them out the error persisted, probably because of what you mentioned